# PyQt5 clipboard is loosing data when copying from application, but works from Excel

Tags: pyqt5, copy, clipboard, paste

I'm subclassing a QTableView to add some functionality - specifically using ctrl+c and ctrl+v (ctrl-> cmd on OSX) to copy and paste values.

I've based my subclass on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715462/how-to-copy-and-paste-multiple-cells-in-qtablewidget-in-pyqt5).

Using this, I'm able to copy from Excel and paste to my tableView without issue.

However, when I copy data from my application, only the last element of the copied string is getting through to the paste statement.

I've added some print statements to show that the clipboard IS getting its text set correctly. However, when I try to read data from the clipboard in my pasteVals method, the clipboard string seems to have changed?

Any help (and context) for this issue would be hugely appreciated! Thanks.

Code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

import numpy as np

class exTableWidget(qtw.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tableModel = tableModel(['Header 1', 'Header 2'])
        self.tableView = tableView()
        self.tableModel._data = [['A',1], ['B',2], ['C',3], ['D',3]]
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel)
        
        self.vlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)
    
class tableModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    
    def __init__(self, headers, data=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._headers = headers
        if data == None:
            self._data = []
            for i in range(4):
                temp = []
                for j in range(len(self._headers)):
                    temp.append(None)
                self._data.append(temp)
        else:
            self._data = data
        if len(self._data) < 4:
            for i in range(len(self._data), 4):
                temp = []
                for j in range(self._headers):
                    temp.append(None)
                self._data.append(temp) 
    
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self,index = 0):
        return len(self._headers)   
                
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if (orientation == qtc.Qt.Horizontal and role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole):
            return self._headers[section]
        else:
            return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) | qtc.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == qtc.Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index,[role])
            return True
        else:
            return False    
        
    def data(self, index, role):
        
        if role in (qtc.Qt.DisplayRole, qtc.Qt.EditRole):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        
class tableView(qtw.QTableView):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        if event == qtg.QKeySequence.Copy:
            print('ctrl+c was hit (copy)')
            self.copyVals(selection)
        
        if event == qtg.QKeySequence.Paste:
            print('ctrl+v was hit (paste)')
            self.pasteVals(selection)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)   

    def copyVals(self, selected):
        print('copy called')
        if selected:
            tempStr = ' '
            row_anchor = selected[0].row()
            col_anchor = selected[0].column()
            for idx in selected:
                print(f'Copying Index [{idx.row()},{idx.column()}] with data {self.model()._data[idx.row()][idx.column()]}')
                value = self.model()._data[idx.row()][idx.column()]
                if value is None or value is np.nan:
                    value = ''
                #Need to convert to STR#
                value = str(value)
                if idx.row() > row_anchor:
                    tempStr = tempStr + '\n'
                    row_anchor = idx.row()
                    tempStr = tempStr + value
                elif idx.column() > col_anchor:
                    tempStr = tempStr + '\t'
                    tempStr = tempStr + value
                else:
                    tempStr = tempStr+value
            qtw.QApplication.clipboard().clear()
            qtw.QApplication.clipboard().setText(tempStr)
            print(f'tempStr added to clipboard: {tempStr}')
            print(f'clipboard from copyVals is: {qtw.QApplication.clipboard().text()}')

    def pasteVals(self, selected):
        print('paste called')
        print(f'cliboard from pasteVals text is: {qtw.QApplication.clipboard().text()}')
        if selected:
            row_anchor = selected[0].row()
            column_anchor = selected[0].column()
            rows = qtw.QApplication.clipboard().text().split('\n')
            print(f'rows are: {rows}')
            valueList = []
            for row in rows:
                valueList.append(row.split('\t'))
            print(f'valueList is: {valueList}')
            pasteRows = max(len(rows), selected[-1].row()-row_anchor+1)
            pasteCols = max(len(valueList[0]), selected[-1].column()-column_anchor+1)
            for r in range(pasteRows):
                if r > len(valueList)-1:
                    rowVals = valueList[-1]
                else:
                    rowVals = valueList[r]
                for c in range(pasteCols):
                    if c > len(rowVals)-1:
                        colVal = rowVals[-1]
                    else:
                        colVal = rowVals[c]
                    idx = self.model().index(row_anchor + r, column_anchor+c)
                    self.model().setData(idx, colVal,  qtc.Qt.EditRole)  
                    
class mainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow): #this will only be run if __name__ == main
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tableWidget = exTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)


if __name__  ==  '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = mainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When I copy the first row, I get the following text:

```py
ctrl+c was hit (copy)
copy called
Copying Index [0,0] with data A
Copying Index [0,1] with data 1
tempStr added to clipboard:  A  1
clipboard from copyVals is:  A  1
```

When I then select cell [2,0] and hit ctrl+v, I get:

```py
ctrl+v was hit (paste)
paste called
cliboard from pasteVals text is: 1
rows are: ['1']
valueList is: [['1']]
```

For reasons I (obviously) don't understand, the clipboard is not retaining the full string it should. It's defalulting to the last value in the string it SHOULD have in full.

I've tried different references to the clipboard (setting self.clipboard, and then referencing self.clipboard), and nothing seems to prevent the first part of the string getting 'lost'. This IS NOT the case when I copy from Excel and then paste. I've dug into the copied strings from Excel and the copied strings from my application, and cannot find a difference - though I may be missing something.

for reference, when hitting ctrl+v, the value the clipboard 'has' does copy - so it works if you only have one column selected. Otherwise, the value from column 1 will get pasted into column 0 and no value will be copied into column 1.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre] within a single code block and also use spaces around operators, as your syntax is difficult to read (see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)).

Comment: **TYPO**: `if event == qtg.QKeySequence.Paste:` -> `elif event == qtg.QKeySequence.Paste:` (otherwise the default copy will be invoked).

Comment: Thanks, @ekhumoro! I feel a bit foolish, but this makes complete sense!